# Can one prove Pappus hexagon theorem with cross ratios alone

Tags: projective-geometry, cross-ratio

Can one prove Pappus theorem knowing that projections don't change the cross ratio and that $(A,B;C,D) = (A,B;C,E) \iff D=E$?

I was reading [this](https://math.mit.edu/%7Enotzeb/cross.pdf) in exercise 6 they say we can prove Pappus theorem with projections and cross ratio, but they don't quite do it.

Pappus theorem is this: Given $A,B,C$ colinear in $r$ and $D,E,F$ colinear in $s$, then $X = AE \cap BD, Y =BF \cap CE, Z= CD \cap AF$ then $X,Y,Z$ are colinear. They hint use to define $P = BF \cap DC$ and $Z' = XY \cap CD$.

[image]

Comment: There are projective planes where Pappus' Theorem does not hold, so you have some assumptions that must be being made here. Can you tell us what they are? Are we assuming that we are working in a projective plane coordinatized by a field?

Comment: they approach projective geometry through euclidean elements (distance, angles). Your comment is really pertinent because it seems like it can't be done the way I wanted. Maybe I should go for Menelaus?

Comment: If you are measuring distance and angles, that seems to suggest you are working over the real numbers (in which case Pappus holds)

Comment: yes, but I wanted to prove it via projections and cross ratio

Comment: @MorganRodgers I was working in $\mathbb P ^2$. What I expected was brainjam answer

Comment: Yes, that is great. You are totally missing my point. It is impossible to prove Pappus' theorem without making some assumptions about the plane you are working in, because Pappus' theorem does not hold in all projective planes. But if you are measuring distances, than $\mathbb{P}^{2}$ is most likely intended to mean $\mathbb{RP}^{2}$, the real projective plane, in which case Pappus' Theorem **does** hold, and cross ratios can be used to prove it (because the value you get from computing the cross ratio is then a real number).

Comment: Note that there are Moufang planes that are Desarguesian but not necessarily Pappian, which have a noncommutative coordinatizing ring, for which the cross ratio can be defined (as giving an element of the coordinatizing ring). But it would be impossible to use the cross ratio in this case to prove Pappus' Theorem. For some more information on this, see http://www.hjms.hacettepe.edu.tr/uploads/b271203a-2591-4e63-aa2a-c241b8e7821c.pdf

Comment: indeed I missed the point a lot, thanks for your comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a proof using cross ratios from [S. Dobos *Cross ratio in use*, The Mathematical Gazette,
Vol. 95, No. 534 (November 2011), pp. 444-453](https://www.jstor.org/stable/23248513):

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Refer to above (top) picture. Suppose that $AC$ and $XY$ intersect on the right hand side at point $K$ (with each line’s extension). Note:

Z’ = AF ∩ XY;

Z’’ = CD ∩ AF;

Z’’’= BZ’’ ∩ XY;

P = BF ∩ CD;

Q= AF ∩ CE.

From point A, then point F and Point B central projection the Cross Ratios evaluation as below:

(X, Z’; Y, K ) = (E, Q; Y, C ) (point A) ;

= (D, Z’’; P, C) (point F);

= (X, Z’’’; Y, K) (point B);

Therefore

Z’= Z’’’ , hence Z'= Z''= Z'''=Z  .

(end)

Answer (score 0):

Refer to above picture. We shall prove that AF Π XY = CD Π XY = Z.
Suppose that AC and XY intersect on the right hand side at point K (with each line’s extension).  From point A projection the Cross Ratio:
(X, AF Π XY; Y, K )
= (E, AF Π CE; Y, C ) (point A)
= (D, CD Π XY; OP, C) (point F)
= (X, CD Π XY; Y, K) (point B)

Therefore
AF Π XY = CD Π XY = Z
(end)

Comment: Use mathjax to make it clear :https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference